# how to get multiple values of selected checkboxes of useres and store in database

Tags: php, sql

Hello I want to get All `$row['student_id']` checked box value and insert their id `$row['student_id'` And their value (0 or 1) in database

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Student Name</td>
  <td><div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name ="check_list[]" class="control-info" value="1">
        </label>
      </div></td>
  <td><div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name ="check_list[]" class="control-warning" value="0">
        </label>
      </div></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: What have you tried, PHP wise?  Html is a long way off from what you need.  And SO is for answering specific programming questions, not providing tutorials on wide subjects.

Comment: `name="check_list[123][]"` 123 being row/student id

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Then how i read it in php to store it

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Then how i read it in php to store it

Comment: Doing a `print_r($_POST);` and it will give you a huge hint where and what came in...

Answer (score 0):

Next time please try to show your working effort. I took my time to work on this script because i see you are new here just like me.So am saying welcome to great stackoverflow.com. This code will work as required.

First create two table  that I commented in the script and insert values as seen there. change the database credentials and run the script and you are good to go

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

/*
CREATE TABLE `student` (
`id` int(4) primary key auto_increment,
`firstname` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`lastname` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`student_id` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '');



CREATE TABLE `new_student` (
`id` int(4) primary key auto_increment,
`firstname` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`lastname` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '',
`student_id` varchar(65) NOT NULL default '');



INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (1, 'Billly', 'Blueton', '100');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (2, 'Jame', 'Campbell', '200');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (3, 'Mark', 'Jackson', '300');
INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (4, 'Billly', 'Blueton', '400');

INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (5, 'Jame', 'Campbell', '500');

INSERT INTO `student` VALUES (6, 'Mark', 'Jackson', '600');
*/



// use PDO
$db = new PDO (
    'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=student_db;charset=utf8', 
    'root', // username

    '' // password
); 


$sql = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM student');
$sql->execute(array());
//$result = $sql->fetch();
$count = $sql->rowCount();

?>

<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
<tr>
<td><form name="form1" method="post" action="">
<table width="400" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
<tr>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF">&nbsp;</td>
<td colspan="4" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Add multiple rows</strong> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">#</td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Id</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>FirstName</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Lastname</strong></td>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>school-id</strong></td>
</tr>

<?php
while ($rows = $sql->fetch()) {
//while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>

<tr>
<td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" id="checkbox[]" value="<? echo $rows['id']; ?>"></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo htmlentities($rows['firstname']); ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo htmlentities($rows['lastname']); ?></td>
<td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><? echo htmlentities($rows['student_id']); ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
?>

<tr>
<td colspan="5" align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><input name="add" type="submit" id="add" value="Add"></td>
</tr>

<?php

// Check if delete button active, start this 
$add =$_POST['add'];
$checkbox =$_POST['checkbox'];
//$delete;
if($add){
for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){
$student_id = $checkbox[$i];






$statement = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO new_student(student_id)values(:student_id)');

if($statement->execute(array(':student_id' => $student_id))){
echo "inserted";
}else{
echo "error";
}

}

}

?>

</table>
</form>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the below framework to iterate over each of **checked** students.

```
if( isset( $_POST['check_list'] ) ) {
        foreach( $_POST['check_list'] as $student_id ) {
            // Do Insert to database here, each value is at $student_id variable
        }
    }
```